# Simplification of a purely real expression from a complex form

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have an expression that is not manifestly real but is real when computed in the correct parameter domain(here, $x<1$).

```
expr = I \[Pi] Sqrt[1 - x^2] + 2 Sqrt[1 - x^2] ArcCoth[Sqrt[1 - x^2]]
```

The following is a table of real values it prints at some particular points that validates my claim:

```
Table[expr, {x, 0.1, 0.2, 0.01}]
```

How to simplify the expression such that it is manifestly real?

I tried:

```
FullSimplify[expr, Assumptions -> x < 1]
```

Yet, it didn't work.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: `FullSimplify[expr // Re //
   ComplexExpand, -1 < x < 1]` yields `-(1/2) Sqrt[1 - x^2]
  Log[(-2 + x^2 + 2 Sqrt[1 - x^2])/(x^2 - 2 (1 + Sqrt[1 - x^2]))]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is real for all real x.

```
expr = I \[Pi] Sqrt[1 - x^2] + 2 Sqrt[1 - x^2] ArcCoth[Sqrt[1 - x^2]];

ceIm = ComplexExpand[Im@expr, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // 
          FullSimplify[#, x \[Element] Reals] &

(*   0   *)
```

You get a piecewise expression for real x

```
ceRe = ComplexExpand[Re@expr, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // 
         FullSimplify[#, x \[Element] Reals] &
```

[image]

```
ceRe // FullSimplify[#, x > 1] &

(*   -2 Sqrt[-1 + x^2] ArcSec[x]   *)

ceRe // FullSimplify[#, x < -1] &

(*   -Sqrt[-1 + x^2] (Pi + 2 ArcCsc[x])   *)
```